# python: print i for i in list

Tags: python

When I printed a list, I got a syntax error when using this method:

```
print i for i in [1,2,3]
```

I knew this is ok when using this method:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    print i
```

and I knew that

```
(i for i in [1, 2, 3])
```

is a generator object, but I just don't get it that why

```
print i for i in [1, 2, 3]
```

does't work. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Have you read http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-print_stmt ?

Comment: first off, what version of python are you using? secondly, have you read how print works? http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not an expression or a function, so you can't use it directly in a comprehension. Use this trick:

```
def f(x): print x
[f(i) for i in [1,2,3]]
```

Note that `(f(i)...)` doesn't work because this just creates a generator which would call `f()` if you iterated over it. The list comprehension `[]` actually invokes `f()`.

**[EDIT]** If you use Python > 2.6, you can achieve the same using

```
from __future__ import print_function
[print(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note the `()` around the argument to `print`.

Comment: This is really not a good idea either though; if you really want to use [`print()` as a function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), use `from __future__ import print_function` instead! Even then, using a list comprehension just for the side effects is a Terribly Bad Idea.

Comment: The question wasn't whether using a list comprehension is a good idea but why it doesn't work. But thanks for reminding me of the `__future__` import.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the question, but I do not agree with your proposed 'trick'; you are teaching a python newbie terrible habits.

Comment: I don't get to use Python often enough :-( Most of my knowledge is still from 2.5.2 where `__future__` didn't support this, yet.

Comment: It's not how you invoke print that I have a problem with, it's that you use a list comprehension just to call a function. It's a terribly bad idea, because you are using a statement that has *one* purpose, for a completely *different* purpose, through a side-effect. That will confuse anyone trying to read that code. They now have to stop and re-read the code to find out why you are not storing the resulting list. Code for the sake of side-effects is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 9):

The list comprehension syntax `x for x in ...` *requires* brackets around it.  That's a syntactic rule of Python, just like requiring indentation, or requiring a colon after `if` or whatever.  `i for i in [1, 2, 3]` by itself is not valid syntax.  You need either `[i for i in [1, 2, 3]]` (for a list comprehension) or `(i for i in [1, 2, 3])` (for a generator comprehension).

Answer (score 3):

The list comprehension syntax (`[expression for loop]`) is a shorthand loop syntax for *producing a list*.

You are not producing a list, you want to print items in a loop. Since you are not producing a python list, you have to use a regular loop.

Alternatively, since all you are doing is printing the items on separate lines, just add the newlines yourself:

```
print '\n'.join(i for i in [1, 2, 3])
```

This produces the same output as:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    print i
```

If you use Python 3, or use `from __future__ import print` at the top of your module and so use the `print()` *function*, you can send all values to the function in one call, and tell `print()` to use newlines in between:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
print(*values, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Print is not a function, it's a statement, and you can't have them in expressions. Just use a regular loop as you don't want to produce a list, that a list comprehension does. In theory you can do (**not that you should. at all**):

```
from __future__ import print_function
[print(my_item) for my_item in [1,2,3,4]]


1
2
3
4
Out[26]:
[None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: Still a bad idea, don't use a list comprehension for it's side effects, please.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters -- I think the answer made it clear that you shouldn't do this...as you are not trying to produce a list. why the downvote then?

Comment: I missed the '(not that you should)` caveat. It cannot be stated loudly enough. Statements for the sake of side effects should at a minimum have a big fat comment in the code to warn unwary maintainers.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters -- added emphasis :)

Answer (score 1):

As an `expression` (in the grammar):

- `[i for i in [1, 2, 3]]` is a list comprehension.
- `(i for i in [1, 2, 3])` is a generator expression.
- But `i for i in [1, 2, 3]` by itself is a syntax error, and that's just the way it is. There must be something surrounding it. Unless you have `(` or `[` around it, it's not a valid `expression`, because the `for` keyword is not valid at that point.

Inside the [print statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), it wants an `expression`.

(As a red herring, `func(i for i in [1, 2, 3])` is permitted as an expression, being a function call with the first argument being a generator expression.)

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid python syntax. The `i for i in [1, 2, 3]` is only valid in a list or generator comprehension, ie. surrounded by `[]` or `()` respectively.

You'll want to use:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: The OP wants to print each item on a newline, not print a list representation.